# Getting callback on Non Activity class like onResume

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on library. Which will be called from other apps. 
Now I need to take permission for certain things like like Application stats. 
Now I am able to show the permission alert box with calling activity context and open the perimission screen.
Here I do not have any mode to check if perission granted or not. As I do know have

startActivityForResult or onResume() functions

Please help me with this.

Can I use

```
public class LibClass extends Activity  {
}
```

and use activity functions.

Comment: An alternative solution is to put `@RequiresPermission(...)` for whichever permissions you need on each of your class's constructors, and then its up to the user of your library to handle getting those permissions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 wanted to know even if this approach is feasible..  I am curious to test this case., It was just a thought I ll make a demo and will check if its working.

Comment: Can u give provide me a example sinppet  to clear the thing. How to implement RequiresPermission

Comment: Sure. Do you want Kotlin or Java? Your question is tagged Kotlin, but your code above is Java.

Comment: I want in java. I tagged kotlin to just broad the approach for other users as well.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work if you require users of your library to inherit from your version of Activity rather than AppCompatActivity. And probably you should inherit from AppCompatActivity in your own library; otherwise users of your library would not be able to use Jetpack features.

An alternative solution is to use the `@RequiresPermission` annotation on your class's constructor to enforce the user of your library to pay attention to what permissions must be granted by their app user before they can safely instantiate your library class. [Documentation here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#permissions) This may be preferred by users of your library so they can use their own flow for granting the permissions, ask for permission at the appropriate time, and show their own messages for explaining the need for the permission.

This requires users to do one of the following to avoid the severe-level warning when instantiating your class:

1. Wrap the instantiation call with a try/catch SecurityException.
2. Use a `checkPermission` or `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` call right before instantiating it (though it seems it does not enforce that they check the appropriate permission).
3. Annotate the call with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")`.

As an example, if your library must use the camera and fine location permissions, it could look like this:

```java
public class Sample {

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION})
    public Sample (@NonNull Context context) {

    }
}
```

If you need only one permission, you can omit the `allof =` and the array braces.

In Kotlin, you have to use the `constructor` keyword to be able to annotate it:

```kotlin
class Sample
@RequiresPermission(allOf = [Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
constructor(
    val context: Context
) {

}
```

Comment: specifically saying I need permission = "android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS";
But I am confuse with above example that how would my lib know that user has accessed it. Where would I get callback so that I can proceed with getting stats.

Comment: Since it's on the constructor, your class can assume that the permission is already granted in any of its code. It would be up to the user of your library to instantiate your class only when the permission is already granted. Your class can immediately start its work after instantiation.

Answer (score -1):

Once permission is granted or declined it will comes 
 **onRequestPermissionsResult** function

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

      //your code
   }
```

for more details refer

[Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: ji. Is it available in Non activity class?